# Launch UIViewController from compose multiplatform

Tags: compose-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform-ios

How to launch iOS's `UIViewController` from `compose multiplatform` like `android`'s `startActivityForResult`. I need to pass data and get result back from `UIViewController`.